# How to change the custom preference layout's imageview programmatically?

Tags: android, android-layout, settings, android-preferences

I used settings activity to let a user select from different resources in my android app. All preference items are checkbox. I've defined a custom layout for each preference and connect it to the checkbox. When I click the preference item it is working properly but I can't understand at which position the preference is. So I want to change the imageview of the custom layout programmatically when I click on the preference item. Is there a way to do that?

Below, the second item is the default text, I want to change the layout to the first one. Everything is working but I want to change the plus image to another image programmatically when I click on this item (to understand that it is checked). Since this is settings activity, I couldn't find a way (there is no findviewbyid etc..) Android behaves the whole custom layout as a checkbox (you can click anywhere on the line)

[image: Snapshot of the Settings]

Settings.xml

```
<PreferenceScreen
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <CheckBoxPreference
        android:layout="@layout/source_item"
        android:key="gundem_haberturk"
        android:title="@string/haberturk"
        android:defaultValue="false"/>

</PreferenceScreen>
```

Custom Layout.xml

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/layout_source_item"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_source_logo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxWidth="100dp"
        android:maxHeight="40dp"
        android:src="@drawable/logo_haberturk"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_source_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Habertürk"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_source_selector"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:src="@drawable/checkbox_unchecked"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Settings Fragment:

```
public class GundemSettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragmentCompat {

    @Override
    public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle bundle, String rootKey) {

        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.gundem_settings);
    }
}
```

Settings Activity:

```
public class GundemSettingsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_gundem_settings);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.settings_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }
    }   
}
```

Settings Activity xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
   tools:context="com.example.hhs.haberler.Settings.GundemSettingsActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/settings_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <fragment
        android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:id="@+id/settings_fragment"
        android:name="com.example.haberler.Settings.GundemSettingsFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a custom `Preference` which extends from `CheckBoxPreference` and use it just like the `CheckBoxPreference`:

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <your.package.name.CustomCheckBoxPreference
        android:layout="@layout/custom_checkbox_preference"
        android:key="custom_checkbox_pref"
        android:title="CustomCheckBoxPreferenceTitle"
        android:defaultValue="false"/>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

Please note that according to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/preference/Preference#setlayoutresource) for the `android:layout` atttribute one has to use specific resource id's for the layout's root `ViewGroup` as well as the `TextView`s for title and summary. This will ensure that the customized `Preference` behaves just like any stock `Preference`.

By overriding `onBindViewHolder(PreferenceViewHolder)` you can "find" the `ImageView` and assign it to a corresponding field *ivSourceSelector*. And by overriding `setChecked()` you can swap the drawables when the checked state of the `Preference` changes.

Having said that, here's the code for `CustomCheckBoxPreference`:

```
public class CustomCheckBoxPreference extends CheckBoxPreference {

    private ImageView ivSourceSelector;

    public CustomCheckBoxPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    public CustomCheckBoxPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    }

    public CustomCheckBoxPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public CustomCheckBoxPreference(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void setChecked(boolean checked) {
        super.setChecked(checked);
        if(ivSourceSelector != null) {
            ivSourceSelector.setImageResource(getResourceId(checked));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(PreferenceViewHolder holder) {
        super.onBindViewHolder(holder);
        ivSourceSelector = holder.itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_source_selector);
        if(ivSourceSelector != null){
            ivSourceSelector.setImageResource(getResourceId(isChecked()));
        }
    }

    private int getResourceId(boolean checked) {
        return checked ? R.drawable.custom_checkbox_checked : R.drawable.custom_checkbox_unchecked;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. Now, I have at least 20 of these checkboxes (sources), can I use the same custom layout and custom class for all of them or should I create layout and new class for all the list items in the preferences.
   
Secondly, the code is working but it gives warning in the settings xml that "com.example.hhs.haberler.Settings.CustomCheckBoxPreference" is not allowed here

Comment: @Hüseyin - you can reuse the layout since you use "findViewById()" in a ViewGroup which contains only one of these inflated layouts. And you can reuse the class (in the PreferenceScreen)  because it will be instantiated as often as necessary. About the warning: sorry but I don't know why. It does not appear in my sample app.

Comment: Sorry for inconvenience. I am trying to use the same layout for all others. But the thing is I need to extract the key values of each preference item from the onBindViewHolder (or from other method), change the textview and imageview in the custom layout according to this information. I've looked at google documents but can't find anything.

Comment: @Hüseyin -did you try `Preference.getKey()` ?

Comment: I've tried but .getKey() method doesn't appear inside custom preference class

Comment: @Hüseyin - are you sure your Preference is extending from CheckBoxPreference from the "com.android.support:preference-v7" library? Because I can override the method - no problem (use "Ctrl" + "O" in Android Studio, then it should show up) BTW sorry but I have to be off now.